# Pull Data From an Array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, request

I have created a simple order form that is selling a variety of cards. These cards come in different colors. The code below shows the colors offered. I need to be able to pull the data from the array below so that I can determine how many of each color did the user select on the form for ordering purposes.

```
Array
(
    [qty] => Array
        (
            ['red'] => 0
            ['blue'] => 0
            ['green'] => 0
            ['yellow'] => 0
            ['orange'] => 0
            ['white'] => 0
            ['black'] => 0
            ['purple'] => 0
            ['teal'] => 0
            ['grey'] => 0
        )
```

Any assistance with this I greatly appreciate.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?  If you have an array of data with a quantity assigned to each index, that's in a pretty usable state.  Please tell us where you want to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $some_input = array('red','red','white');
    $a =array( 'qty' => array(
    'red' => 0,
    'blue' => 0,
    'green' => 0,
    'yellow' => 0,
    'orange' => 0,
    'white' => 0,
    'black' => 0,
    'purple' => 0,
    'teal' => 0,
    'grey' => 0,
));
    $f = function($x) use(&$a)
    {
        if(in_array($x, $a['qty']))
        {
            $a['qty'][$x]++;
        }
    };
    array_map($f, $some_input);

    var_dump($a);
?>
```

You can see the code running [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MZ23yu) click in the button paste

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to display the info on a page?

If so, this should do the job for you (assuming your array is called $array):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($array['qty'] AS $colour => $total) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $colour; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```